# Add a checkbox to enable/disable overwriting files during installation in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

My installer copies over a folder with multiple files in it.

Inside there are some settings file that I want the user to have the option to
decide if they want to overwrite existing ones when installing on top of an older folder.

Currently, I'm using,

```
[Files]
Source: "MyFolder\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Example list of files to protect: `settings1.txt`, `settings2.txt`, `myconfig.txt`

How do I add a checkbox during the setup wizard where it defaults to checked and overwrites all files, but if unchecked it will only overwrite non-listed files?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest solution is to:

- Add an `overwrite` ["task"](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection) to implement the checkbox.
- Duplicate your `Files` entry. One copy will belong to the `overwrite` task. And the other will have [`onlyifdoesntexist` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=onlyifdoesntexist) will `not` belong to the `overwrite` task.

```
[Tasks]
Name: overwrite; Description: "Overwrite existing files" 

[Files]
Source: "MyFolder\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs onlyifdoesntexist; \
    Tasks: not overwrite
Source: "MyFolder\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; \
    Tasks: overwrite
```

---

If you do not like to duplicate the code, you can use preprocessor to reuse the repeated piece of code.